# How keep text right side like this in below image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have done this using below code but my text stays at left side it needs to start from right side like image if anyone have idea about this so please help me .
I have included all details about this image and code for this problem check this sources and help me for it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #00CED1;
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white outline: none;
  opacity: 3;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00a2a4 50%, #e6e6e6 50%);
  float: right;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 3;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="width: 43%;">
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <span>CREATIVITY</span> <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <span>CRITICAL THINKING</span> <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="70" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <span>CREATIVITY</span> <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: add `text-align: right` to the class `.sidecontainer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add align right in the container `text-align: right;`

I have update your snippet.

```css
body {
  background-color: #00CED1;
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right; 
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white outline: none;
  opacity: 3;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #00a2a4 50%, #e6e6e6 50%);
  float: right;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 3;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="width: 43%;">
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <span>CREATIVITY</span> <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <span>CRITICAL THINKING</span> <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="70" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <span>CREATIVITY</span> <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your code:

```
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this should fix your code

```
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flex box:

```
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```